# Codesandbox - change language

Tags: codesandbox

Is there any way to change language in Typescript error popup messages in codesandbox?

Below error message is in PL

[image]

But when I hover HTML error, I am getting error in EN language:

[image]

Note that error ts(2531) is in PL

Comment: In `VSCode` you can change your language using the `Configure Display Language` options (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/locales) but this option seems to be not present in `CodeSandbox`, so it might be disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an error before but has been fixed in prod, checking as of today, this issue should be gone.